# What does 还要 mean in this sentence? "释然啊，你现在心里在想什么，我恐怕比你还要清楚。"

Tags: simplified-characters

大家好！

What does 还要 mean in this sentence?  "释然啊，你现在心里在想什么，我恐怕比你还要清楚。" It was in a Chinese novel that I was reading called 释然的修行.
Thanks!

Comment: “还要清楚” means “更加清楚” or “更清楚”

Comment: cf.＂外国人实用汉语语法＂第八章｜表示比较的方法｜第一节｜用＂比＂表示比较｜（四）介词结构＂比。。。＂后边，谓语前边可以用副词＂更＂、＂还＂或＂还要＂作壮语，表示程度上更进一层。例如：这个公园比那个（公园）更美（＂那个公园＂相当美）今天比昨天还热。（＂昨天＂相当热）他用的方法比我的（方法）还要简单。（＂我的方法＂相当简单）这个城市比那个城市还要繁华。（＂那个城市＂相当繁华）

Answer (score 1):

“还要” is used to express a high degree. This sentence means I know more about your desires than you do.

Comment: Welcome Caroline. Could you expand your answer a little bit, maybe analyzing the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

"还要" means "more" here, so "还要清楚" means "clearer."

Other expressions of "clearer" include:

> 更清楚
>
> 更加清楚
>
> 清楚得多

Assuming "释然" is a person's name (Shiran), the entire sentence means

> Shiran, I'm afraid I'm clearer about what you're thinking now than you are.